# Executing a c operating system inside VMWorkstation

Tags: virtualization, operating-systems, c

I am planning on starting development a small, simple operating system, however I am unsure about a starting point.Would running the code inside a VM without a OS in it be the best approach at developing an operating system? If so could someone give a brief overview of the steps to take to execute the code as the VM boots up.

Comment: Operating system *is* the code that runs when VM boots up. If you want to run arbitrary code without OS, you have to run it the same way you'd run OS.

Comment: Yes how can I point the VM start executing my code via an ISO file? since the code will be the OS itself.

Comment: The same as you would if that ISO was actually a physics disk in a physical machine being booted by a "real" BIOS, so all the materials regarding that should still apply to basic stuff in the VM (and likewise once/if you install to disk, physical or virtually, so boot sectors etc etc).

Comment: [Boot sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector), [El Torito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard))

Answer (score 2):

I think a good staring point will be to take a look at the [COSMOS](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/) :

```
Cosmos is an operating system "construction kit", built from the ground up around the IL2CPU compiler in C# ...
```

There is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99928/Develop-Your-Own-Operating-System-in-C-or-VB-NET) :

Develop Your Own Operating System in C# or VB.NET

[image]

> This is your operating system running in VMWare Player! Cosmos can of
>   course also be booted in VMWare Workstation, Hyper-V, Virtual PC, or
>   on real hardware. But by default, Cosmos uses VMWare Player because it
>   is both free, and reliable. Cosmos can even debug in Visual Studio,
>   even when running on another machine.